# Makefile doesn't work after changing the project directory

Tags: makefile, compilation

I and my friends are doing OS. Everything was OK, before we changed the files location. It says:

> make: no rule to create "obj/drivers/loader.o" needed for kernel.bin.

We don't know why.

You can see the source code at https://github.com/Langriklol/pluto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the directories in the rules are wrong.

You have a file named `loader.s` and want to create a file named `obj/drivers/loader.o` from this file.

None of the rules in your `makefile` matches this:

The rule `obj/%.o: drivers/%.s` would be suitable to create `obj/loader.o` from `drivers/loader.s` but not to create `obj/drivers/loader.o` from `loader.s`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I fixed it.